# SQL SERVER 2000 is Slow & linked server send an error "Server doesn't exist or Access is denied"

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a problem in my SQL SERVER 2000 , 
the server is so slow when i made any query 
and recently i couldn't link with other SQL servers. 
The message is "the server doesn't exists or access is denied".

In spite of that the linked servers were working well and i can access them remotely & the service pack is SP4...

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the meagre information... check the network status if everything is slow full duplex, cable OK etc

Or another random guess, old server or very old install or buy new stuff (based on running SQL Server 2000)